# Connecting a servo to GPIO when using touch screen to GPIO socket

Tags: gpio, pi-3, touchscreen

I bought a Raspberry pi 3, along with a touch screen that connects to the board, to all the GPIO pins.
I wonder how can I use the GPIO port for additional functionality, e.g. connecting servo motors to specific GPIO port.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried?

Comment: I am using this screen: [http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/4DPi_24_HAT/](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/4DPi_24_HAT) , which plugs directly on the GPIO ports. Therefore I cannot connect a servo, which I want to work when something happened. I wish to have the screen functionality, but still use GPIO for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the GPIO are not being used by the touch screen you can use them to control servos.

The question is really how do I connect wires to the GPIO if a touch screen fits over the pins.

Perhaps solder to the underside of the Pi expansion header where the pads are exposed?

Comment: You could use something like the [Pimoroni Pico HAT Hacker](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/pico-hat-hacker), but that requires soldering. But if you do go that route, you can still access all 40 pins. Just make sure the pins you are going to use are not used by your HAT.